State not updating component
I have a YouTube player component that receives a state prop from its parent but it doesn't seem to re-render on change, it is supposed to add a class which is added when I set the initial value of the prop to true when the state is set initially to false. I can see it change to true in the components tab but the class is not added. please help
YouTube component

'use client'
import { React, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

const YoutubePlayer = ({ id, isPlayerReadyFunc, playersAreReady }) => {
    const isPlayerReadyRef = useRef()
    const [test, setTest] = useState(false)
    isPlayerReadyFunc(isPlayerReadyRef, false)
    useEffect(() => {
        const player = new window.YT.Player(`${id}`, {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: id,
            playerVars: {
                color: 'white',
                controls: 1,
                playsinline: 1,
                rel: 0,
            },
            events: {
                onReady,
                onStateChange,
            },
        })

        function onReady(event) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                isPlayerReadyFunc(isPlayerReadyRef, true)
            }, 1000)

            console.log('ready')
        }
        function onStateChange(event) {}
    }, [])

    return (
        <div
            className={'youtube-div' + (playersAreReady ? ' scale' : '')}
            id={`${id}`}
        ></div>
    )
}


export default YoutubePlayer


parent

'use client'

import YoutubePlayer from '@/components/YoutubePlayer'

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
    const YTPlayersAreReadySetRef = useRef(new Set())
    const [playersAreReady, setPlayersAreReady] = useState(false)
    const [tags, setTags] = useState()
    const [beats, setBeats] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getBeats = async function (tags) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3500/api/beats`)

                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error("couldn't get beats from server ")
                }
                const beats = await res.json()

                setBeats(beats)
            } catch (err) {
                throw err
            }
        }
        getBeats(tags)
    }, [tags])
    const addStateToReadySet = (isReadyRef, boolean) => {
        isReadyRef.current = boolean

        YTPlayersAreReadySetRef.current.add(isReadyRef)
        const arrayFromSet = [...YTPlayersAreReadySetRef.current]

        if (
            arrayFromSet.every((i) => {
                return i.current === true
            })
        ) {
            setPlayersAreReady(true)
        }
    }

    return (
        beats && (
            <div>
                <h1>videos</h1>
                {beats.map((beat) => {
                    return (
                        <YoutubePlayer
                            playersAreReady={playersAreReady}
                            isPlayerReadyFunc={addStateToReadySet}
                            key={beat.YTid}
                            id={beat.YTid}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    )
}



use playersAreReady prop  as a dependency in the useEffect hook within the YoutubePlayer component . If it's not included, the effect won't be triggered when the prop changes. And , Update Class Based on Props i.e Instead of relying on internal state (test), directly use the playersAreReady prop to conditionally add the class in the YoutubePlayer component.

isPlayerReadyFunc(isPlayerReadyRef, false) runs every time the component renders, so it's always false

@RavinaSarda : the test state is not being used in the current code it's there from when I was debugging. I don't want useEffect to run again I want the component to re-render after receiving a different state prop

@Konrad you are right but it has no effect on the playersAreReady state since I never set it to false again. it's also confirmed in the dev tools

The problem was that the youtube API , takes over the div element and turns it into an iframe so it is not part of the react component anymore, kinda makes sense.
